# Add Custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in RestTemplateBuilder with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest

I need to add a **Custom Header** in all my RestTemplate Client requests. So I implemented `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. And I add the interceptor in my `RestTemplateBuilder` config like shown below. The problem is that when the RestTemplate makes the HTTP call it throws following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory
```

RestTemplate Bean Creation :

```
@Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(restTemplateProps.getMaxConnectionsPerPool());
    poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(restTemplateProps.getMaxDefaultConnectionPerRoute());
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager).build();
    ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
    restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder.additionalInterceptors(new MyClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
    return restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory).build();
  }
```

Also, I am updating the timeouts later in below code:

```
  protected void setRestTemplateTimeouts() {

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory rf =
        (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    rf.setConnectTimeout(restTemplateProps.getConnectionTimeout());
    rf.setReadTimeout(restTemplateProps.getSocketTimeout());
  }
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was, I was trying to set the **connect and read timeouts** after setting the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`.

In my `setRestTemplateTimeouts()` method when I try to fetch & typecast `requestFactory` to `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, I get the `ClassCastException` exception because `restTemplate.getRequestFactory()` returns `InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory` instead of `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`. This is because I added an **interceptor** in my **restTemplate** object.

Solution is to **set the timeouts before setting** **interceptor** because you can't set timeouts after setting an interceptor. Refer the code below:

```
@Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(restTemplateProps.getMaxConnectionsPerPool());
    poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(restTemplateProps.getMaxDefaultConnectionPerRoute());
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(restTemplateProps.getConnectionTimeout());
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(restTemplateProps.getSocketTimeout());
    restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder.additionalInterceptors(new MyClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
    return restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory).build();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i manage to get the interceptor to log both request and response without throwing exception - Attempted read from closed stream.

```
 @Bean
 public RestTemplate getRestTemplateConfig()
            throws KeyStoreException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {


        SSLContext context = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("/opt/cert/keystore.jks"), 
                        "password".toCharArray(),
                        "password".toCharArray())
                .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setSSLContext(context)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

       //Provide a buffer for the outgoing/incoming stream, allowing the response body to be read multiple times
        // (if not configured, the interceptor reads the Response stream, and then returns body=null when responding to the data)
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory));
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>singletonList(
                new RestTemplateInterceptor()));
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jacksonSupportsMoreTypes());
        return restTemplate;
    }

    private HttpMessageConverter jacksonSupportsMoreTypes() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList( MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
        return converter;
    }
```